# Why should SeekBar be on 'onCreate' method?

Tags: android

I wrote the code for a timer like below, but if I wrote it in a separate method, not in pre-created method like onCreate(), it doesn't work as I expected. But if I put the body part of the method in 'onCreate()', it works just as fine.

Are there some rules or differences between writing a method in 'onCreate()' method or independently?

```
public void seekBarController(View view){

    SeekBar timerSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.timerSeekBar);
    final TextView timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);

    timerSeekBar.setMax(10*60);
    timerSeekBar.setProgress(30);

    timerSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            int minutes = (int) progress / 60;
            int seconds = (int) progress % 60;

            String minutessString = seconds < 10? "0"+ Integer.toString(minutes): Integer.toString(seconds);
            String secondsString = seconds < 10? "0"+ Integer.toString(seconds): Integer.toString(seconds);

            Log.i("this is progress", Integer.toString(progress));
            timerTextView.setText(minutessString+":"+secondsString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seekbar, like any View needs an Activity and is part of/owned by that Activity. It will be created when the Activity is created. Thus the `findViewByID` method can only be used when the activity has actually been created and after the Content (the layout) has been setup (via setContentView).

It's unclear what View you pass to the method, but, the following keeps your method separate though calling it appropriately (nothing is passed to the method, it uses the instance's Activity for the findViewById) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        seekBarController();
    }

    public void seekBarController(){

        SeekBar timerSeekBar = (SeekBar) this.findViewById(R.id.timerSeekBar);
        final TextView timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);

        timerSeekBar.setMax(10*60);
        timerSeekBar.setProgress(30);

        timerSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                int minutes = (int) progress / 60;
                int seconds = (int) progress % 60;

                String minutessString = seconds < 10? "0"+ Integer.toString(minutes): Integer.toString(seconds);
                String secondsString = seconds < 10? "0"+ Integer.toString(seconds): Integer.toString(seconds);

                Log.i("this is progress", Integer.toString(progress));
                timerTextView.setText(minutessString+":"+secondsString);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {    
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onCreate() is automatically called "under the hood" by the Activity's class. It is automatically called when the activity is first created. See the Android documentation on [Activity Lifecycles](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

Without knowing much of your Activity's implementation, I would say putting that timer's code in the onCreate method or have the onCreate method call that method.

Answer (score 0):

Activity class provides a core set of six callbacks: onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), onStop(), and onDestroy(). The **onCreate()** fires when the system first creates the activity.